# How long will my homemade marinade with orange juice last?

Tags: sauce, marinade, vinegar, juice, lime

I have a question regarding a marinade that I made. It contains juice. How long will it keep in the refrigerator? I have the final marinade in a air tight glass jar.

Here are the ingredients:

- 6 Scotch bonnet or spicy habanero peppers (seeds and stems removed)
- 6 scallions (chopped)
- 4 cloves of garlic
- 1 yellow onion (chopped)
- 1/4 cup vegetable oil
- 1/4 cup brown sugar
- 1/4 cup white vinegar
- 1/4 cup orange juice
- 3 tbsp of fresh thyme leaves
- 3 tbsp ground allspice
- 3 tbsp soy sauce
- 1 tbsp fresh ginger (chopped)
- 1 tbsp fresh ground black pepper
- 1 tbsp kosher salt
- 1 tbsp fresh lime juice
- 1 tsp nutmeg
- 1 tsp ground cinnamon

Comment: That sounds really good. Hot (very hot), and awesome.

Comment: It's impossible to give an exact time, but given the sugar and vinegar, probably a couple of weeks. Don't quote me on that - it depends on several factors, not least the cleanliness of the jar. If you boiled the marinade and put it in a sterilised jar it would probably keep for months.

Comment: Hello Tony D, welcome to the site. It's very good that you state the ingredients, but please clarify how you prepare the marinade. Boiling everything vs. just combining the ingredients raw should make much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

2 weeks minimum. If it's in an air tight and sterilized jar which isn't constantly being opened and closed. I'd push more for a couple of months maybe longer.

All the acid in there, sugar and salt work as great preservatives and the spices also will help. The 2 things you need to be watching for are either the oil going rancid or the juice fermenting. **Fermenting if probably the most likely**. Both should be quite easy to spot.

Fermented sauce will start bubbling at the top, and if you shake the jar it'll fizz up like you'd expect from a bottle of soda. Also if the jar "pops" when you open it this is also a good sign fermentation has begun.

Here's a link for helping spot rancid olive oil the same rules apply pretty much to all oils http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2013/08/05/olive-oil.aspx