# How long will my homemade lemon juice marinade last?

Tags: food-safety, sauce, marinade

I have a question regarding a marinade that I made. How long will it keep in the refrigerator? I have the marinade in a air tight plastic container.

Here are the ingredients:

- 1 lemon/lime zest
- 1 lemon/lime juice
- 1 clove of garlic
- 1/2 tbsp balsamic vinegar

Comment: It's impossible to say, a few days to a week probably, however it will lose potency and flavor. You're better off using a marinade right away.

Comment: Also, the amount/tempo of spoilage is determined by the hygiene in your kitchen, which we don't know anything about, and is hard to quantify anyway.

Comment: With that small quatity (maybe 1/4 cup in all), it will spoil faster.

Comment: It could even gain flavor from extraction.... I guess any safe/unsafe spoilage discussion would need more knowledge about the exact ingredient qualities (acidity of lemon, how the garlic was cut....)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that freshly squeezed lemon or lime juice does NOT last overnight (if one were making salad dressing, for example).

If you're making a marinade, I would squeeze the citrus immediately before adding it to the meat. Then remove ALL the air out of the bag (search "water displacement" method); this will prolong the potency of the citrus.

The garlic will be better if fresher too.

**EDIT**:

Per @Cindy, here's a search for finding out about the [water displacement method](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove%20air%20using%20water%20displacement&oq=remove%20air%20using%20water%20displacement&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3912859.3916800.0.3918008.17.17.0.0.0.0.178.2181.0j15.15.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.157...35i39k1j0i13k1.0.VC-FjXaSxhc)

Comment: Hello TdeV and welcome. Just a friendly suggestion: Rather than post an answer that requires someone to search for information, perhaps you could describe the method, citing sources if needed. You could also give alternatives, in this case perhaps vacuum sealing. You can always edit your posts by clicking on 'edit' under your post.

Comment: @Cindy. Many folks don't have vacuum sealers and the traditional water displacement method for getting rid of air is a good choice. There are LOTS of videos and pictures all over the internet. You want me to paste a google search string?

Comment: I know that many may not have vacuum sealers. But we try to give answers that benefit many, not just the poster. We suggest adding links for sources and adding info in because the links may go down. All said, your answers have been good. Just trying to help you acclimate to the site. :)

Answer (score -1):

[How long will my homemade marinade with orange juice last?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/50313/how-long-will-my-homemade-marinade-with-orange-juice-last)

Your question is very similar to the question from the above link. This is the most accurate answer I could find. The shelf life of food kept inside the refrigerator will all depend on the way the food was prepared, considering that all the ingredients you used were fresh. And since you mentioned that you used an airtight container, it may also give a longer storage time, provided that it is kept tightly closed without unnecessary opening. It is also nice to know that citrus fruits can go into fermentation stage which will definitely cause a change in the taste. So up to two weeks is the best time to store the marinade.

Comment: Yes it's the exact same answer I've found before posting here, it's just that my ingredients and quantity were different. I then wonder 1) what specific ingredients are key to preserving the marinade? Should I take out the citrus at all? 2) What minimum quantity (in grams/ml) of marinade should I prepare every time to make it last the longest? and 3) I'll basically open and close the container once every 2 days (just for when I grill chicken) Is it going to make much difference or is it just fine?